# Pandas merge, join Problem with joining column

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I have to big tables
For example

```
df1 = 
Name Age
Alex 20
Bob  19
Don  56

df2 =
Name PL
Don  Python
Bob  C
Alex java
```

I want to get

```
df3 = 
Name Age PL
Alex 20  Java
Bob  19  C
Don  56  Python
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new there,

Comment: you can find solutions in [pandas-merging-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name')
```

The result is:

```
   Name  Age      PL
0  Alex   20    Java
1   Bob   19       C
2   Don   56  Python
```